# View pushed outside horizontally constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

How do we put a long `Textview` and an icon horizontally without having the `Textview` to push the icon outside the view.

Played with `constrained_width` etc, but to no joy.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:text="Text in the middle pushes the edit icon out of view oh noh!" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want the `Textview` and the icon to be in the center aligned (horizontal). But as the text grows, the `Textview` pushes the edit icon outside the view. How do we put a `Textview` (variable width) with anything else horizontally without the `Textview` pushing others outside the screen.

Icon pushed outside bounds

[image: Icon pushed outside bounds]

Need it to be something like this, with the views occupying the whole width
[image: Need it to be something like this, with the views occupying the whole width]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need chainStyle and need to modify constraint for view which work like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        tools:text="Text in the middle pushes icon out of view oh noh! But we Resolved issue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/edit"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]